# Writing expression for field calculator in Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, syntax

I have a script where I calculate a couple of variables, add a new field then need to do a field calculation that field. Once I get everything set up, it's the expression that I have a hard time figuring out. I am using **ArcGIS 10.2**

```
denominator = 0.14
arcpy.CalculateField_management("My_Table", "LQ", ( ( "!Foreign_Born_Population!" / "!Population!" ) / denominator ) , "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I am thrown an error stating it cannot parse the string but I thought by wrapping the field name in `!!` that it would recognize it as a field.

If I were to open the field calculator in the attribute table and type in a function using VB Script, the function would look like:

```
( [Foreign_Born_Population] / [Population] ) / 0.14
```

I also tried using the VB Script in the function but that did not work.

I have seen a couple different solutions including with and without using a cursor. Do I need to use a cursor?

How can I write this function?

Comment: Are both of your fields classified as number fields?  If one of them is a string field, that can mess things up.  What happens when you just run the 1st part of the calculation without the / 0.14?  And then run the / 0.14 on the field you just calculated?  Also, have you tried running it without the quotes around the fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotations around the field names and pass the entire expression as a string. It can also be helpful to break out the expression on its own line when troubleshooting.

```
denominator = 0.14
expression = '( ( !Foreign_Born_Population! / !Population! ) / {} )'.format(denominator)
arcpy.CalculateField_management("My_Table", "LQ", expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: Worked as expected on a test feature class, thank you so much! **Question:** Do you mind explaining why 1) the first part is entirely entered as a string and the denominator gets `.format()`, 2) what the { } do in the code, how does it know to reference to the denominator? Are there instances when multiple { } may be used? How would it know what to reference to?

Comment: The expression parameter has to be a string so it is helpful to use the built-in `format()` method on the string to perform the inline substitution of `denominator`. 
You can have many substitutions. The `{}` notation serves as a placeholder and will fill them in the order you pass them in the parameters (e.g. `'{}{}{}{}'.format('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` becomes `abcd`. More info here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format